# How to reverse regex pattern?

Tags: python, regex

Let's say I have this string:

`exampleString = 'Hello @world! This is a #sample ^string 5with @words that ^start with symbols.'`

And I want to print all words that does not start with any symbol.

`pattern = '[@^#!%&*].*?\s'`

I've got this pattern that selects all words that starts with any kind of symbol. And now comes my question: How to reverse it so it matches the exact opposite?

I tried `(?!)` but it seems to do nothing.

Comment: `'(?![@^#!%&*]).*?\s'` is one option or `'[^@^#!%&*].*?\s'`

Comment: Your `(?!)` denotes a look*ahead* but it reads like you needed a look*behind*... To get all words preceded by start or a white-space: [`\b(?<!\S)\w+`](https://regex101.com/r/an01Td/1) this looks behind if there is *not* a non-whitespace before the `\b` word-boundary, which can only happen at start or preceded by a whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

you can negate a set of charachters by using ^at the beginning of the brackets, for example [^a-z] means any character except for leters between a and z

so using

```
[^@^#!%&*]
```

will match any words starting with any letter or symbol but @, ^, #, !, %, & and *

if I use the Regex

```
[^@^#!%&*\s][^\s]*
```

which means:

```
[^@^#!%&*\s]         : 1 char not symbol nor space
            [^\s]*   : 0 or more chars not space
```

I will have as positive @**word** because "word" match this (**w** is the first char and **ord** is the following 3 chars)

so I need to say that the first letter also must be the first letter of the word, so before I should have a space or the start of the sentence

this is the final regex

```
(^|\s+)[^@^#!%&*][^\s]*
```

explained:

```
(^|\s+)                   : the start of the sentence or more than one space
       [^@^#!%&*]         : followed by a character not in the set
                 [^\s]*   : followed by 0 or more chars not spaces
```

note the word 5with is also matched because 5 is not in the "forbidden list of characters"

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm trying to understand and learn regex and it's quite tough.

Edit:
I've tested it and unfortunetally it also matches the words that comes directly afterwards. '@world!' is selected and printed as 'world!'

Comment: true... edited and corrected

Answer (score 0):

In my view, the easy way to do this is to come at the logic from the other direction and print all words that start with a character from the set you want, i.e. `[a-zA-Z0-9]`. (If underscores were acceptable, you could use `\w`.)